# Split Value in column to rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I used the Apriori model in R to find a association rules.
The model output look as following:

```
  id                                 lhs      rhr      support confidence     lift
    1         {BENEFIT SERVICE,ERBORIAN} {BENEFIT} 0.001362644  0.6163793 2.557921
    2 {BENEFIT SERVICE,MAKE UP FOR EVER} {BENEFIT} 0.002982571  0.6113281 2.536959
    3          {BENEFIT SERVICE,CLARINS} {BENEFIT} 0.002649057  0.5914894 2.454629
```

my goal is to split the lhs column and actual duplicate the other column consistently.

as follow:

```
   id                     lhs                rhr      support confidence     lift
    1         BENEFIT SERVICE            BENEFIT  0.001362644  0.6163793 2.557921
    1         ERBORIAN                   BENEFIT  0.001362644  0.6163793 2.557921
    2         BENEFIT SERVICE            BENEFIT  0.002982571  0.6113281 2.536959
    2         MAKE UP FOR EVER           BENEFIT  0.002982571  0.6113281 2.536959
    3         BENEFIT SERVICE            BENEFIT  0.002649057  0.5914894 2.454629
    3         CLARINS                    BENEFIT  0.002649057  0.5914894 2.454629
```

any idea how to do this kind of data manipulation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use function `separate_rows` from `tidyr` package. You might need to remove the brackets `{}` first.

Comment: Thanks @AntoniosK it's work perfect. Any idea how I can use to remove the brackets? when I try to use the lapply(df1, gsub, pattern='{', replacement='')
I'm getting error invalid regular expression '{', reason 'Missing '}'

how I can use the '{' that R will not think it's part of code

Comment: try `\\{` instead of `{` (and  `\\{|}` is even better)

Comment: @VincentBonhomme 
df2 <- lapply(df1, gsub, pattern='\\{', replacement='')

what I missing here? still not work
Thanks

Comment: try `gsub("\\{|}", "", df$ldhs)`. not sure how your data is formatted.